# Prepare data for previously trained LibSVM classifier

Tags: machine-learning, svm, data-transformation, libsvm

I trained a LibSVM classifier, with scaled features in the interval $[-1;1]$ with this equation:

$$x'=2\frac{x-\min x}{\max x - \min x}-1$$

I am happy with the trained model and its accuracy on the testing data, and want to use my model on new data as I receive it.

I receive 1 new row of feature data, and want to predict the class of it using my trained model. Is it necessary to scale the new data features to the interval $[-1;1]$? If so, do I need to retrain my model each time I get a new row of features, since the max/min values used for scaling could potentially change with new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that

1. The new data originate from the same distribution as your training set,
2. The training set is large enough to represent the underlying distribution,

You simply use the same values of $\min x$ and $\max x$ that you used to transform the training data, no need to re-train the model everytime. Note that both of the assumptions should usually hold.

Comment: Thanks. Yes the equation can just be modified with some additional multiplication and subtraction to shift to a [-1 1] interval. So by using the same min x and max x values, what happens to scaling if the new set of data presents a new "maximum x" and new "minimum x"

Comment: Okay, I updated the formula in the question. You are still using the old maximum and minimum that you extracted from the training set. This way you are transforming the data the same way you transformed the training set, thus working in the same space.

Comment: Thanks Jan, could you clarify one more thing. ... essentially I am no longer getting values in the same interval if I receive new max or min values for x, for example if my data set for a feature is {1,2,3,4} and I scale to interval [0 1] i will get {0, .33, .66, 1}. Now I retrieve a new data point of 5. Using the same min and max to scale, will put it at 1.33 which is outside the [0 1] interval. Is this okay for the SVM model?

Comment: Yes, that is expected behavior and it is okay for the SVM. It simply means it is larger than any value the model has seen during the training, but it should handle it.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much. I was having trouble deciding on if this is okay to do. Since I am new to cross validated, I can't mark your answer as useful just yet, but thanks a bunch!!